# Contador de data incremental

Tags: sql, auto-incremento

Olá,

Pessoal, possuo a seguinte estrutura:

Tabela AB9010

Contem os campos:

```
AB_DATA (Varchar(8), NOT NULL)
R_E_C_N_O (PK, BIGINT, NOT NULL)
```

Ela contem mais de 1M de registros o campo R_E_C_N_O contem o ultimo valor de 1000000, e preciso preencher cada linha do campo AB_DATA com uma data inicial de 19900101 até a data 20220331.

Não importando se não preencher todos os recnos, mas que fosse até a ultima data 20220331

Como gostaria que fosse incrementado as datas de forma que elas fossem com um contador, e quando chegar ao fim do mês em questão, ele vire para o mês 02 e assim por diante, e também os anos.
Exemplo:

```
AB_DATA = 19901231 | R_E_C_N_O = 1
AB_DATA = 19910102 | R_E_C_N_O = 2
AB_DATA = 19910103 | R_E_C_N_O = 3
```

Eu tentei fazer assim:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE
DECLARE @EndDate DATE
DECLARE @StarRec INT
DECLARE @EndRec INT
SET @StartDate = 19000101 SET @EndDate = 20220331
SET @StarRec = 1 SET @EndRec = 1000000
UPDATE AB9010 SET AB_DATA = @StartDate + 1
WHERE R_E_C_N_O = 1 + @StartRec
```

Mais ai retorna um erro, que eu entendi, mas não sei como vou contornar, sem deixar do tipo DATE pra que ele faça a contagem de acordo as datas certinho.

> "Conflito no tipo de operando: int é incompativel com date"

Não sei se ficou claro oque eu precisaria, se alguém puder me ajudar.

Obs: sou analista de suporte, e estou tentando entender, pra popular esses dados em base, pra simular um processo de uma rotina que olha para o campo AB_DATA preenchido, pra validar performance.

Comment: Maldita Data do Protheus :) .?. Qual SGBD ? Sql Server ? No set das datas se precisa converter o formato , creio ser a "112" , https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/  precisaria também de um FOR ou WHILE para variar o recno ou um  Cursor lendo a tabela

Comment: Para Oracle UPDATE AB9010 SET AB_DATA = TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('19900101','YYYYMMDD'+R_E_C_N_O_,'YYYYMMDD');  se tiver 1m de dias ...

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.